# If Harry was to look in the Mirror of Erised at the end of Book 6, what would he see?

Tags: harry-potter, magic

In the first book, we all know Harry saw

> his Mother and Father

in the Mirror of Erised, for the first time.

I wonder, what could he have seen at the end of the 6th book, when

> Dumbledore and Sirius died! And also he came to know of the horcruxes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Apparently, Rowling answered this question in an interview, now online at [Accio Quote](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2005/0705-tlc_mugglenet-anelli-2.htm),

> **Q:** If Harry was to look in the Mirror of Erised at the end of book six, what would he see?
>
> **JKR:** He would have to see Voldemort finished, dead gone, wouldn't he? Because he knows now that he will have no peace and no rest until this is accomplished.

Comment: If it weren't for this quote from JKR, my answer would have been, "He sees himself, choking the **** out of Snape."